# Change class active on click menu list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the **activeTest** class of section tag on click, and remove the class that from the section he was, and put on the section I expect to;

I tried the `parent()` and `sibling()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#test123 .links").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa").hasClass('active')) {
      $(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa.active").removeClass("active");
      $(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa.active").siblings().addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.conteudo-projetoPesquisa {
  display: none;
}

.conteudo-projetoPesquisa.active {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test123" class="row center-xs around-md">
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <a href="#!" class="links">institucional</a>
  </li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 maioresMelhor">
    <a href="#!" class="links">Maiores e Melhores</a>
  </li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 faleConosco">
    <a href="#!" class="links">Fale Conosco</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container active">1
</section>
<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container">2
</section>
<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container">3
</section>
```

Comment: `$(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa")` is selecting all the elements.  If any of them has the active class, that if is going to be true, always.  Also, how are you determining the relation between the link clicked and the section that should display?  Positional?

Comment: Personally i'd stick some sort of data field on the links like `data-section="..."` and then put what's in the section as a class on the section that should show when that link is clicked.  Then it's a semi-simple remove the active class from all sections, and then put it on the section that has the class matching your data element.  This way it is not position based and less fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Your Code

If your order of links is always the same as the sections you can use the index of the clicked link to determine which section to make visible.

Using [**index**](https://api.jquery.com/index/) on `$("#test123 .links")` allows you to query for the index of the clicked link.

Using [**eq**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) on the collection of `$(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa")` using the previously determined index will select the section in the same index the clicked link is in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#test123 .links").click(function(e) {
    var index = $("#test123 .links").index(this);
    $(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa").removeClass('active');
    $(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa").eq(index).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.conteudo-projetoPesquisa {
  display: none;
}

.conteudo-projetoPesquisa.active {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test123" class="row center-xs around-md">
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <a href="#!" class="links">institucional</a>
  </li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 maioresMelhor">
    <a href="#!" class="links">Maiores e Melhores</a>
  </li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 faleConosco">
    <a href="#!" class="links">Fale Conosco</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container active">1
</section>
<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container">2
</section>
<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container">3
</section>
```

---

### Alternative using Data Attributes

However, if you have any control over it, it would be better to "pair" the elements. If you for example can populate a data attribute to assign the matching section number to the link itself than the order is not important.

```
<a href="#!" class="links" data-section-id="1">...
<a href="#!" class="links" data-section-id="2">...
```

Then you can assign the same value to each section and therefore "pair" the elements.

```
<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container active" data-section-id="1">...
<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container active" data-section-id="2">...
```

Then you can use the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#test123 .links").click(function(e) {
    var sectionId = $(this).data('sectionId');

    $(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa").removeClass('active');

    $(".conteudo-projetoPesquisa[data-section-id=" + sectionId + "]").addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.conteudo-projetoPesquisa {
  display: none;
}

.conteudo-projetoPesquisa.active {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test123" class="row center-xs around-md">
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <a href="#!" class="links" data-section-id="1">institucional</a>
  </li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 maioresMelhor">
    <a href="#!" class="links" data-section-id="2">Maiores e Melhores</a>
  </li>
  <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 faleConosco">
    <a href="#!" class="links" data-section-id="3">Fale Conosco</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container active" data-section-id="1">1
</section>
<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container" data-section-id="2">2
</section>
<section class="conteudo-projetoPesquisa container" data-section-id="3">3
</section>
```

Comment: @Fran if you may change the question title to one more especific and objective. I'm not so good with descriptions, and It was not finding any question for this problem, may help other user.

Comment: @LucasTelesx I think the title contains the relevant words and SEO should be able to pick it up OK.

Answer (score 0):

To connect links  and tabs you should use data-attr

Something like this

```js
 $('[data-tab-trigger]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is('.active')){
            return false;
        }
        var $wrap = $(this).parents('.tab-wrap'); 
        $('[data-tab-trigger]',$wrap).removeClass('active');
        $(this,$wrap).addClass('active');
        $('[data-tab-section]',$wrap).removeClass('active');
        $('[data-tab-section="'+$(this).data('tab-trigger')+'"]',$wrap).addClass('active');
    })
```

```css
.hide-tab{
  display:none;
  padding:20px;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}
.hide-tab.active{
  display:block;
}
.tab-wrap{
  margin:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-wrap">
  <div data-tab-trigger="1">show first tab</div>
  <div data-tab-trigger="2">show second tab</div>
  <div class="hide-tab" data-tab-section="2">
     second tab
  </div>
  <div class="hide-tab" data-tab-section="1">
     first tab
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-wrap">
  <div data-tab-trigger="1">show first tab</div>
  <div data-tab-trigger="2">show second tab</div>
  <div class="hide-tab" data-tab-section="2">
     second tab
  </div>
  <div class="hide-tab" data-tab-section="1">
     first tab
  </div>
</div>
```